# I want to query by date stamp which is not a ISODate format.The date is the following format Datestamp: 2016-03-08T02:20:20

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongodb. I want to query by DateStamp. The date stamp is as follows

Datestamp: 2016-03-08T02:20:20

I used ISODate query which didn't work

```json
db.GeneralLiability.find({ "session._Datestamp":{"$gte":ISODate("206-03-08T02:20:20")}})
```

Also I tried using:

```json
db.GeneralLiability.find({ "session._Datestamp": {'$regex':'2016-03-08'}})
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to query. Please help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

Show the output of the query.
You have written 206 instead of 2016.

```json
db.GeneralLiability.find({ "session._Datestamp":{"$gte":ISODate("206-03-08T02:20:20")}})
```

Try this it should work:

```json
db.GeneralLiability.find({ "session._Datestamp":{"$gte":ISODate("2016-03-08T02:20:20")}})
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo.It is 2016

Comment: I tried db.CPP.find({ "session._Datestamp":{"$gte":ISODate("2016-04-11T17:49:31")}}) it is showing as zero records.